# metaclass conflict when making an abstract base class with a metaclass

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a library which permits expansion by registering custom render elements.

I had the idea of using a metaclass on `AbstractElement` to automatically register all non-abstract classes subsequently derived from it.  This is what I came up with:

```
import abc
import inspect

class AbstractElementMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, basses, attrs):
        cls = super(M, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, basses, attrs)
        if not inspect.isabstract(cls):
            register_element(cls) # Defined elsewhere in the module

class AbstractElement(abc.ABC, metaclass=AbstractElementMeta):
    pass
```

But this results in the following error:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a
           (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Still sort of wrapping my head around the internal class structure and mechanisms of python. Is what I want to do possible, and if so, how can I go about it?  I want to avoid making my users use the metaclass themselves (I'd just make a decorator if I had to).